# Encrypted configuration file JNDI provider

Tags: java, configuration, jndi

Is there a free and/or open-source library which provides a JNDI provider stored as something simple like a configuration file which includes encryption for passwords?

It seems like JNDI is the J2EE API for providing container-managed configurable items but I can't find a general, container-independent solution out there.  Am I missing the point of JNDI?  Alternate solutions are welcome but I'd like to avoid including large-scale dependencies (such as Spring or Maven).

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit like taking a drug because you want one of its side effects, but...

The POJava Persistence library has a JNDI provider intended for the purpose of supporting JUnit test cases running outside of a container.  It's just an in-memory implementation, but the same library can also serialize objects to/from xml, so you could extend it to load from a file on init and drop to a file whenever appropriate.